# Java + Selenium, Chrome: how can I check a box?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I'm a beginner at Selenium, so I need help with this. I want to check the box:

[image: Click me]

I already tried that:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("order[terms]")).click();
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the error raised? By the way, the check box has an id "order_terms", you can find it by id.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("order[terms]")).sndKeys(Keys.SPACE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to click on first input tag which is hidden. You need to click on second input tag which has id order_terms.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("order_terms")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findelement(By.xpath("//*[@id='order_terms']")).click();
```